# What's the "routing-instance" in networking?

Tags: router, networking

When I read this [Article](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB31929):

there is a term `routing-instance`, how to understand this term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some routers can be configured into separate, virtual routing entities. Each of these entities has its own routing instance with an independent routing table.

Think of each instance as a separate router, all living in the same box.

Answer (score 1):

As per Juniper Documentation

"A routing instance is a collection of routing tables, interfaces, and routing protocol parameters. The set of interfaces belongs to the routing tables, and the routing protocol parameters control the information in the routing tables. There can be multiple routing tables for a single routing instance—for example, unicast IPv4, unicast IPv6, and multicast IPv4 routing tables can exist in a single routing instance. Routing protocol parameters and options control the information in the routing tables."